# How to convert polar system to latitude and longitude

Tags: android, geolocation, maps, geocoding

i am trying to develop an android app . I use a web service that require my location in latitude and longitude (where i am standing) and giving a feedback another location data. But, the another location data is given with polar system which the origin of polar system is the place where i stand.

My question is, how to convert the given polar system data (distance, and degree from the north)  to be the another location's latitude and longitude. ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I think what you want to do is called a 'Bearing/Range' calculation. See the section 'Destination point given distance and bearing from start point' at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formula:

```
Latitude = distance * (Math.cos(degree));
Longitude = distance * (Math.sin(degree));
```

Comment: Is it valid ? since the earth is spherical ?

Comment: Do you mean our current location (where we stand ) doesn't affect the "another" location's latitude and longitude.

Lets imagine an example:
@Swetank Imagine we get a data distance = 100 meters, and the degree of the position is 45degree. 
how could we say the latitude and longitude of "another" location is equal when we stand on (0,0)  or in (-106,100) ?

Comment: Every location has fixed latitude and longitude which never changes.

Comment: let say we are standing in China, and i get "another" location from server which has a distance about 100 meters from my location pointing 45degree from my point if i face to the north,compare it if i stand in australia and i get "another" location from server which has a distance about 100 meters from my location pointing 45 degree from my point if i face the north.
Both of them are not equal longitude and latitude right ?

Comment: Let me explain more clear about my question, if i have a distance from my current location and a the Location degree, counted if i face the north, How to convert it to another latitude and longitude.
It must be different if i stand in China and Brazil even the distance and the degree are both equal.